# MS Access - Display days as number of years in combobox

Tags: ms-access

The row source of my combobox is set to "365;730;1095;1461;1826".

I need to store the values in my table as number of days but I want to display them as years (1;2;3;4;5) from my combobox.

Is it possible? How?

I've tried =Year([Duration]) but it doesn't work.

Comment: `=[Duration]/365`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *two* columns:

```
"1;365;2;730;3;1095;4;1461;5:1826"
```

and hide the second column.

That said, the count will only always be true for *four years* due to the leap years.

Comment: No need to be super accurate so leap years won't be a problem. Thanks.